# on estimating converging series with the integral test

Tags: calculus

Under the hypothesis of the integral test, given a series $S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ whihc is convergent, we obtain the following estimation

$$ \int_{n+1}^{\infty} f(t) dt \leq S - s_n \leq \int_n^{\infty} f(t) dt $$

where $f(n) = a_n$ and $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is the partial sums of the series

Question. To estimate this sum, can we just take any $n$? say $n=3$, then I can use this to estimate the sum of the convergent series:

$$ \int_4^{\infty} f(t) dt \leq S - s_4 \leq \int_3^{\infty} f(t) dt $$

can we take a different $n$? to estimate the sum from above and then use another $n$ to estimate the sum from below?

Ex, Suppose I want to estimate $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ which I know converges.

Then, can I do

$$ \sum \frac{1}{n^2} \leq s_4 + \int\limits_3^{\infty} \frac{ dx}{x^2} $$

to estimate from above. And now if I want an estimate from below, I wanna pick different $n$, say $n=1$:

$$ \int\limits_2^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2} + s_1 \leq \sum \frac{1}{n^2} $$

Can I do this?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you give an example that's a bit more concrete?

Comment: I updated the question. Does it make sense now?? Im trying in general to estimate convergent series that satisfy the hypothesis of the itnegral test.

Comment: I don't see why not. It seems trivially true or am  I wrong?

Comment: Hold on, I will update my question with an example

Comment: @JackyChong I updated the question now.

Comment: Yes. You can certainly do that. Draw a picture to convince yourself.